# Conditional Facebook Share and Like links

Tags: facebook, conditional-tags

I am using [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/), and have enabled "Recommend" and "Send" links.

Unfortunately they are appearing in too many places. Can I limit their appearance using `is_category('catttttt')`  style conditionals?

Happy to switch to a different Facebook Connect plugin in order to gain this finegrained feature.

Answer (score 0):

I read a little into the plugin you're using and it says that it offers shortcode functionality. So I presume somewhere in the settings page for the plugin there is an option to stop it from injecting into all pages. The downside is that you'll have to manual add in the shortcode to get the recommend and send links to show in your articles, but it sounds like that's what you want.

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to automatically assign to posts of certain categories ONLY

Comment: Is it absolutely required to use a plugin to add in the Facebook code? It seems overkill considering the code from the Facebook generator is so minimal anyway. You can always add it in manually yourself into the templates and that way you'll be able to control how and when it displays by using the is_page, is_category functions. Using plugins does save time, but in this instance it's preventing you from implementing a very straight forward and simple solution.